# How to Deploy/Publish two projects in ASP.NET MVC with VS (Codeplex: AspNet.Identity.MySQL)

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net-mvc, iis, codeplex

I have created an ASP.NET MVC 5 project with Entity Framework and a MySQL database. In Debug-mode everything works perfectly, but now I would like to publish it to my IIS-Server.

1. The first project in my Solution is AspNet.Identity.MySQL which
   allows me to use Entity Framework in combination with Identity 2.0
   and MySQL. It is from codeplex. https://aspnet.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#Samples/Identity/AspNet.Identity.MySQL/
2. The second project is my ASP.NET MVC application.

Publishing the second project by itself is no problem. I just don´t know how to publish the first project (AspNet.Identity.MySQL).

Long story short,
**I have this and don´t know how to deploy/publish it via File-System:**

[image: IdentityWeb is the ASP.NET MVC Appliaction]

IdentityWeb is the ASP.NET MVC Appliaction.

Thanks for your help,
Beardy Bear

Comment: The first project `AspNet.Identity.MySql` is a class library, so it's output is a DLL only.  When you build the solution, a DLL is output into the bin folder.  If project `IdentityWeb` has a reference to the other one, the DLL for it will appear in the bin for that project too.

Comment: IdentityWeb already has a reference to AspNet.Identity.MySQL. Does that mean I only have to publish IdentityWeb and it´s done?

Comment: Yes, I would have thought so. As long as when you publish the `IdentityWeb` project, it has the DLL `AspNet.Identity.MySQL.dll` in the bin, then you're good to deploy :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first project `AspNet.Identity.MySql` is a class library, so it's output is a DLL only. When you build the solution, a DLL is output into the bin folder. If project `IdentityWeb` has a reference to the other one, the DLL for it will appear in the bin for that project too.

As long as when you publish the `IdentityWeb` project, it has the DLL `AspNet.Identity.MySQL.dll` in the bin, then you should be able to deploy your ASP.NET MVC application to IIS.